# query data from PHP and create ScrollList in unity C#

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I have an InputField in Unity and On End Edit I set it to call function PopulateList() to show all result that match query command. If I got only one result my program run perfectly but somehow if I got two or more result the program will loop add the second result of query no matter how much result from query and I don't know why or how to fix it. Please help me find the way.

** I apologize for my bad English writing skill

here is my Unity C# code :

```
public class CreateSearchResult : MonoBehaviour {

public Text searchInput;
public GameObject searchResult;
public Transform contentPanel;
public List<item> itemList;
public RawImage img;
public string queryURL = "http://http://localhost/dmcs/getdata.php?keyword=";
public string imgURL = "http://http://localhost/dmcs/people/";

public void PopulateList()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetResult());
}

IEnumerator GetResult()
{
    //Clear previous search result
    foreach (Transform child in contentPanel)
    {
        GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
    }
    WWW result_get = new WWW(queryURL+searchInput.text);
    yield return result_get;
    if (result_get.error != null)
    {
        print("There was an error : " + result_get.error);
    }
    else
    {
        string[] result = result_get.text.Split(";".ToCharArray());
        for (int i=0; i<result.Length-1; i=+5)
        {
            string name     = result[i + 1];
            string building = result[i + 2];
            string floor    = result[i + 3];
            string room     = result[i + 4];
            WWW wwwimg = new WWW(imgURL + result[i] + ".png");
            yield return wwwimg;
            itemList.Add(new item(name, building + ", Floor " + floor + ", Room " + room, wwwimg.texture));
        }
    }

    //Create ScrollList of GameObject
    foreach (var item in itemList)
    {
        GameObject newResult = Instantiate(searchResult) as GameObject;
        SampleButtonScript buttonScript = newResult.GetComponent<SampleButtonScript>();
        buttonScript.nameLabel.text = item.name;
        buttonScript.placeLabel.text = item.place;
        buttonScript.exImage.texture = item.pic;

        newResult.transform.SetParent(contentPanel);
        newResult.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    }
    //Empty the list after created ScrollList
    itemList.Clear();
}
```

}

PHP code :

```
<?php
// Configuration
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'dmcs';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='. $hostname .';dbname='. $database, $username, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '<h1>An error has occurred.</h1><pre>', $e->getMessage() ,'</pre>';
}
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR building LIKE '%$keyword%' OR floor LIKE '%$keyword%' OR room LIKE '%$keyword%'");
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$result = $sth->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $r) {
    echo $r['people_id'], ";", $r['name'], ";", $r['building'], ";", $r['floor'], ";", $r['room'], ";";
}?>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the comment about SQL Injections i recommend you to format your data in a common format like [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), it will make your life easier as your project increases or changes, in this example i'll use JSON because is easier to understand

```
<?php

// Configuration
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'dmcs';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $hostname . ';dbname=' . $database, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '<h1>An error has occurred.</h1><pre>', $e->getMessage(), '</pre>';
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE %:keyword% OR building LIKE %:keyword% OR floor LIKE %:keyword% OR room LIKE %:keyword%");
$sth->execute([':keyword' => $_GET['keyword']]);
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json['keyword'] = $sth->fetchAll();
$json['content'] = count($json['keyword']);

echo json_encode($json);
```

Then in Unity first you need to add a JSON library like [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) just download it and copy it to your Scripts Folder, then you just do something like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using SimpleJSON;

public class CreateSearchResult : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string queryURL = "http://http://localhost/dmcs/getdata.php?keyword=";
    public string imgURL = "http://http://localhost/dmcs/people/";

    public void PopulateList()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetResult());
    }

    IEnumerator GetResult()
    {
        string jsonData = "";

        WWW result_get = new WWW(queryURL + searchInput.text);
        yield return result_get;

        if (result_get.error != null)
        {
            print("There was an error : " + result_get.error);
        }
        else
        {
            JSONNode jsonNode = JSON.Parse(jsonData);
            int resultQty = int.Parse(jsonNode["content"]);

            for (int i = 0; i < resultQty; i++)
            {
                string name = jsonNode["keyword"][i]["name"];
                string building = jsonNode["keyword"][i]["building"];
                // And so on... 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved it. Problem is at the for loop i=+5 I changed to i++ and use i*5 in the code can fix it or use as your code above can fix it too.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, very helpfull and very few informations are available with SQL / PHP and JSON for Unity. Your example is really instructive.